# Checking some expressions in the paragraphs using regular expressions with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to use regular expressions in PHP to check if a text has at least two paragraphs, the first beginning with "In fact" and another beginning with "I suggest."

For example, I tested this:

```
$text = "In fact Paris is more beautiful than Berlin.
I suggest we go to Paris this summer."
$value = preg_match ( "/ (^ In fact (.))  (I suggest). * /", $text);
echo $value;
I get $value = 0;
```

I get $value = 0;

I do not know why, please help.

Comment: Use on of the online Regex testers to develop some Regex foo: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
$text = "In fact Paris is more beautiful than Berlin.
I suggest we go to Paris this summer.";
if(preg_match ( "/^In fact(.*)I suggest/s", $text)){
echo 'true';
} else {
echo 'false';
}
```

In your regex this `. *` is allowing one of any characters `.` then any number of spaces `*`. This `(.)` is allowing one space.

I'm not seeing what you are trying to capture so I removed your capture groups. The `s` modifier allows the `.` to match new lines.

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/vW2oZ8/1 
PHP Demo: https://eval.in/584773

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the modifier `\s` and the quantifier `*`( [example](https://regex101.com/r/sJ6oN1/1))

```
(^In fact (.*))\s(I suggest(.*))
```

The `\s` matches any white space character, like `\n` and `\r`, the newline bunch. Your code should look like this now:

```
$value = preg_match ( "/(^In fact (.*))\s(I suggest(.*))/", $text);
```

Now `$value` will be 1.